# Explain how the FFREE instruction works

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

how does the ffree instruction excatly works ?
    FFREE   Free register
when i have in FPU STack:

```
  st2 5 , st1 2, st0 7
```

then after these instruction(ffree) i have..

```
   st 1 5, st0 2
```

is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it clears the register without modifying the stack pointer. Whatever register you gave as an argument will be set as empty, but the others will be unchanged.

http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap3.htm#ffree

Comment: hm, so in my example, if i use Ffree st1 , then after that i have:    st2 5 , st1 0??, st0 7

Comment: ALmost, it will not contain 0, it will contain garbage.

Comment: so will i be able to use it again ? Or first i have to make sure that i  turn st1 to '0' ? with some kind of operation ? For example, i would like to have st1 '1' after  ffree st1 operation

Comment: You'll need to load something into it to use it again. If you want st1 to contain a value, why do you want to ffree it?

Comment: no, no i only ask of my curiosity. then for example i can load into it variable jedynka: dd 1.0   ?

Comment: You can't load anything into it unless the spot is st0

Comment: so for example i first use fxch st1